# Inputting hours as hh, instead of hh:mm in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, office365

I'm working with duration, not dates. I formatted my cell to [h] because I only want to see 10, 30, etc instead of 10:00:00 which is the default for duration, but when I input the values I still need to write 10:00:00, if I write 10 it will read it as 10/01/2001 00:00:00.
I would like to be able to write 10 and make excel interpret that as the number of hours. Is it possible?

Comment: If you just need to fill in whole numbers, why must excel be aware they are hours ? Just fill in your number and you're good...

Comment: You can insert number directly as hours...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that's what you want but you can type your hours as "10" in cell A1 and add this formula to B1

```
  =A1&":00:00"
```

and format it to duration